# OSX 10.11.6 Make cant find headers specified --include-dir not working

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, makefile

I'm attempting to compile code on OSX 10.11.6
The header file to use is in:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/
                        i386/
```

So as a test, the c code incudes i386/_types.h thats located in [.../usr/include/i386/_types.h] so I used:

```
make --include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/
```

However, it *still* doesn't find the _types.h file under the i386 directory and throws an error stating file not found!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I should have used `clang` instead of `g++`, from there the library path argument had to be specified along with the framework,
e.g.

```
clang -stdc++ -framework <Framework>
```